# Maximum minimum degree of a graph embedded on a surface

Tags: topological-graph-theory

We shall consider only simple graphs. 
Let $G$ be a graph 2-cell embedded in a surface having 
Euler characteristic $\chi$.  Let $\delta(G)$ be the minimum degree of $G$. 
 Define

$\delta_{\chi} = max  \{\delta (G)$   :    a graph  $G$ is 2-cell embedded 
in a surface with  Euler characteristic $\chi \}$.

I know that  $\delta_2 =5,  \delta_1 = 5, \delta_0 =6, \delta_{-1} =6$.

Is there formula for $\delta_{\chi}$?